# how to make a dynamic url to a page template?

Tags: php, wordpress

in vue.Js 'router' we have this thing of
`<router-link :to="{ name: 'user'}">User</router-link>`
so we can redirect just using the template name without uri or url

is there someting similar in wordpress ?
because i want to create a custom login page but for url i used
`<a href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('login.php'); ?>">Login</a>` which doesn't work
then i used  `<a href="/login">Login</a>` but as you can see i used the page slug here
and if admin changes that slug i will have to change my php code i want something dynamic like in VusJs case

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [wp_login_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/) for the login url.
- [wp_logout_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/) for logout
- [wp_registration_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_registration_url/) for registrations
- [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) if you know the Post/Page ID (if empty, the current post/page's id would be used)
- [get_site_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/) and [get_home_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/)

Other than the above functions, to resolve your problem, I would suggest using a URL Redirection plugin to redirect the traffic when the admin changes the slug of the url. Certain plugins smells it when the page/post slug is changed, and automatically add a redirection condition. You could use that which makes life easier.